# Append a space separated string to a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list, append

I have a string and a list like this-

```
s = "ball apple snake car"
l = ['banana','toy']
```

Now I want to add it to an existing list so that the list looks like-

```
l = ['banana','toy','ball' ,'apple' ,'snake ','car']
```

Comment: `l.extend(s.split())`

Comment: l = l + s.split()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
l = l + s.split(' ')
> ['banana', 'toy', 'ball', 'apple', 'snake', 'car']
```

With `s.split(' ')`, you transform the string to a list of the words. With `l +`, you append that list to the end of the other list.

Answer (score 0):

Well it seems the simplest answer is to split the string by the spaces and append it to the list:

```
s="ball apple snake car"
l=['banana','toy']
s_list = s.split()
for item in s_list:
    l.append(item)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> l += s.split()                                                                                                                             
>>> l                                                                                                                                          
['banana', 'toy', 'ball', 'apple', 'snake', 'car']
>>>
```